# Using 2 separate queries to check if email and username exist in the db

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to get my PHP script to check if both email and username already exist in the DB and then present messages if they do - I initially was able to check for just one with success but now that I am attempting to check both before the insert I am having some problems.

Could somebody give me some suggestions as to what I am doing wrong here?

```
// Check if simple anti-bot test is correct
if ($human !== 5) {
    $errHuman = 'Your anti-spam is incorrect';
}
else {
    if (!$errEmail && !$errUsername && !$errPassword && !$errPassMatch && !$errHuman) {

        $query1="SELECT email FROM blog_members WHERE email='$email'";
        $query2="SELECT username FROM blog_members WHERE username='$signupusername'";
        $result1=mysqli_query($conn, $query1);
        $result2=mysqli_query($conn, $query2);

        if ($result1 && mysqli_num_rows($result1) >=1) {
            $error = "Email already exists!";
        }else if ($result2 && mysqli_num_rows($result2) >=1 ) {
            $error = "Username already exists!"
        }else {
            $query="INSERT INTO blog_members(username, password, email) VALUES ('$signupusername', '$signuppassword', '$email')";
            $result=mysqli_query($conn, $query);
            ?>
              <script type="text/javascript">
                alert("User created, please login from the homepage!");
                window.location.href = 'http://www.mywebsite.co.uk/index.php#login';
              </script>
            <?php
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens? Do you get an error?

Comment: did you try like  this WHERE email='$email' and username='$signupusername'  or use separate if not else if

Comment: You are wide open for SQL injection. Since you're using mysqli, take advantage of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). This also helps prevent pesky quoting issues.

Comment: @Daniel I get This page isn't working because the landing page has an include to this PHP page. The site works if I stick to just 1 query

Comment: @aynber definitely am aware of this, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do this:

```
$query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM blog_members WHERE username='$username' OR email='$email'", $conn);
$result = mysqli_num_rows($query);

if ($result != 0) {
    // What happens if it exists
} else {
    // What happens if it doesn't exist
}
```

Tell me any errors that occur or if anything goes wrong.

Comment: The query itself seemed to be the problem, it works now. However in a slightly different way to your answer.